# How to I detect text in real-time?

Tags: python-3.x, text, webcam, live

Currently this is my code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

This code reads text from an image and prints out the letters. I want to learn how to get text from a webcam while it's running.

Comment: Consider capturing a single frame from the webcam, as an image, and detecting text in that single frame image.

Comment: @gammazero Ok, if I used this method, will it take the frame then running webcam?